# Regarding initialising pointer variables

Tags: c

In C, these statements:

```
char *c={'q','w'};
```

and

```
int *c=123;
```

both give error/warning for the fact that initially 
`c` will be holding any garbage value and by assigning value directly to that variable I might be accessing protected memory.

But when I defines the pointer it doesnt give any error by considering it as string:

```
char *c="jayesh";
```

I am not been able to figure out the logic behind the string definition. Please help me understand the same.

Warnings which i got:

Warning:excess elements in scalar initializer[enable by default]
    Warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast[enable by default]

Comment: You should give the warnings you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *c={'q','w'};
```

doesn't work because `c` isn't an array, and you can't use array initializer syntax on a non-array object.

```
char *c=123;
```

doesn't work because you're attempting to convert an integer value (`123`) to a pointer without a cast; note that

```
char *c = (char *) 123;
```

would "work" in the sense that the initialization would succeed, although `123` is most likely *not* a valid memory address.

```
char *c = "jayesh";
```

works because string literals like `"jayesh"` are array expressions, and under most circumstances an array expression will be converted to a pointer expression, and the expression's value will be the address of the first element of the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration.

So what's happening is that the address of the first character (`'j'`) is being assigned to `c`.

If your declaration had been

```
char c[] = "jayesh";
```

then `c` would be created as a 7-element array of `char`, and the *contents * of the string literal would be copied to it.

Answer (score 1):

`int *c` stores the address of an integer variable but not an integer value. That's why you get an error/warning.

`char *c={'q','w'}` is an invalid initialization in c. Because, pointers can point to a block of allocated memory. But there is no memory allocated for `{'q','w'}` itself in this way.

If you want you can use

```
          `char *c=(char[]){'q','w'}`
```

Because, in this way no invalid initialization is done since `{'q','w'}` type converted into `char[]` which can be pointed by `c`.

> Agree with your answer about char *c ,but by assigning char *c="jay"
>   here also I am defining an array as c={'j','a','y','\0'} so whats the
>   basic difference between both these except a '\0'

Since, the type of `{'w','q'}` is not resolved to `char[]`, when you use `char *p={'q','w'};`. But when you use `char *p="hello"`, the type of `string literal` is resolved to be `char array`. That's how `C language` defines `string literals` they are stream of characters but not stream of `int` s or anything else.

When compiled, every such string literals are stored in static storage location and are perfectly a `char array` and hence can be pointed by `c` which is of type `char *`. But this is not the case with those array `{}` syntax.Because, {'q','w'} can be an integer array also with out first converting it to char[], how is it eligible for assignment for something that is `char *`? For example, `int p[]={'1','2'}` compiles fine. Because pointer arithmetic for is affected by their type which is affected by the `type`s `size`.`{'1','2'}` takes `2*sizeof(int)` if it is an `int` array and `2*sizeof(char)` if it is a `char` array.

Comment: Agree with your answer about char *c ,but by assigning char *c="jay" here also I am defining an array as c={'j','a','y','\0'}  so whats the basic difference between both these except a '\0'.

Comment: Got most of the things but correct me if I am wrong.By doing        char *c=(char[]){'q','w'} I am assigning the address of 'q' to c(which is pointer variable), and in the previous expression    "char *c={'q','w'}"     c variable was expecting an address but I was assigning an array to it.

Comment: @jayeshhathila yeah you are assigning the address of `q` and `char *c={'q','w'}` c variable is expecting the address of the character.....but compiler couldn't know whether {'q','w'} is of type char or int or else...actually you are not initializing with correct type to be strict.... that's the reason may be `char *c={'q','w'}` was not possible though `char *p="hello"` is possible... I'm expecting this may be the reason language designers did this way...I can't know their actual intentions though

Answer (score 0):

Most pointers to the type used to determine the char array. And to be precise, the array - this is a pointer / offset. When you create a variable `char *ch` this is equivalent to `char ch[]`but you can not define a variable. You must specify a fixed size for the array. `char ch[256]` and this is the C string. Suppose you have created a variable and write string `char ch[256] = "qwerty";` You can refer to any character. `ch[2]`(they return "e"). In this case ch - is a pointer to the start of array. And `ch[2]` sets the offset to the 2 bytes size of char.

Comment: Char ch[]="qwerty" will also work I need not to declare the size if I am defining the string at the declaring point.